# File extension hook in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to run a hook for specific file extensions (i.e. not modes). I have zero experience with elisp, so I cargo-cult coded this:

```
(defun set_tab_mode ()
    (when (looking-at-p "\\.cat")
    (insert "OK")
    (orgtbl-mode)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'set_tab_mode)
```

(Should set orgtbl minor mode for files with suffix .cat and insert text "OK", i.e. it's not only a mode setting question).
Unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun my-set-tab-mode ()
  (when (and (stringp buffer-file-name)
             (string-match "\\.cat\\'" buffer-file-name))
    (insert "OK")
    (orgtbl-mode)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-set-tab-mode)
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use lambda in `auto-mode-alist`:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.cat\\'" . (lambda ()
                               ;; add major mode setting here, if needed, for example:
                               ;; (text-mode)
                               (insert "OK")
                               (turn-on-orgtbl))))
```

Comment: He's trying to set a minor mode though, you're method only works for major modes unfortunately.

Comment: @bneil you can put arbitrary code in lambda, no matter if it sets major mode, minor mode or does some other thing.

Comment: I was looking for a way to turn on two modes at once for a given file type, and while I knew about `auto-mode-alist`, I did not know you could use `lambda`s with it. This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Even if you used this to set a minor mode, wouldn't it override the associated major mode?