# emacs: open all .txt files in a specific directory in a specific major mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

EDIT: It turns out that the second edit to my .emacs file actually works. (See the comments below this entry.)

I tried a couple of addition to the .emacs to make all txt files opened in emacs use orgmode. They did not work. How can I make it happen?

```lisp
;;SET EMACS AS DEFAULT MAJOR MODE TO FOR ALL FILES WITH AN UNSPECIFIED MODE
(setq default-major-mode 'org-mode)

;;OPEN ALL TXT FILES IN ORGMODE
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.txt$" . org-mode))
```

Additionally:

It would be even better to open only txt files in a certain directory orgmode. Any hint as to how that could be done would also be appreciated.

Comment: Your code should open txt files in org-mode. At least, it works for me. Check your .emacs file if you dont modify a mode for txt files later.

Comment: I don't it's a very short .emacs cause I'm new to it. But I just realize I now get this message every time I start emacs: "Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/Klsrd/.emacs':

End of file during parsing: /Users/Klsrd/.emacs

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace." Could that be the cause?

Comment: There is something wrong with your .emacs. Remove everything from it and put just (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.txt$" . org-mode)) to see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a hook which verifies the file directory and modifies the buffer mode:

```lisp
(add-hook 'find-file-hooks 
          (lambda ()
            (let ((file (buffer-file-name)))
              (when (and file (equal (file-name-directory file) "c:/temp/"))
                (org-mode)))))
```

As an alternative you can add the mode line **in the beginning** of your text file. In this case emacs will set the specified mode.

```
; -*- mode: org;-*-
* header 1
** header 2
```

Comment: You don't need a ; before `-*- mode: org -*-`

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is using directory-local variables.  This is nice because you can put a file in any directory where you want this behavior to engage, and it works recursively in any subdirectories.

Create a file called `.dir-locals.el` in the desired directory.

Here are the contents:

```
((nil (eval . (if (string-match ".txt$" (buffer-file-name))(org-mode)))))
```

Read this like so:  for any major-mode (`nil`), `eval`uate the following form:

```
(if ....  (org-mode))
```

Answer (score 4):

The regex in `auto-mode-alist` could be something more complex, like `"^/path/to/.*\\.txt$"`

Answer (score 0):

I glued together some code from Oleg Pavliv's answer here, and from yibe's at [elisp - File extension hook in Emacs - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6886731/2533127)

```
(defun use-org-mode-for-dot-txt-files-in-owncloud ()
  (when (and (string-match owncloud buffer-file-name)
             (string-match "\\.txt\\'" buffer-file-name))
    (org-mode)))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'use-org-mode-for-dot-txt-files-in-owncloud)
```

This way, though ownCloud Web and phone apps are currently friendly only with `.txt` files, from my PC I can use Emacs' Org-mode for them.

(If I set all `.txt` files to use Org-mode, it breaks `todotxt-mode`.)

(Note that `owncloud` is a string variable equal to my ownCloud path.)